# Laravel redirect route with variable not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and when I use `with` it doesn't flash the data over.

If I use

```
Session::flash('test', 'test');
```

Then it shows the session flash data.

If I put the ->with on the index it also doesn't work either.

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return Redirect::route('registration::index')->with('test1', 'test');
}

public function index()
{
    return view('registration.index');
}
```

View:

```
{{ var_dump(Session::all()) }}
```

What's going wrong here..?

Comment: What Laravel version are you using? And how do your route definitions look?

Comment: did you `use Session;` in your controller?

Comment: aren't you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors. use Session is in the controller & the version is the latest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2 the `StartSession` middleware is no longer added to the global `$middleware` list in the `App\Http\Kernel` class. Instead it's added to the `web` middleware group, so the session doesn't start automatically with a request. You have two options to fix this:

**1.** Add the routes that need to use the session in a route group that uses the `web` middleware  group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'ControllerClass@index');
    Route::post('store', 'ControllerClass@store');
});
```

**2.** Move the middleware from the group to the global middleware list so that the session is started on every request:

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
];
```

Comment: Still does not work. Can you please explain how to access the variable? How to retrieve variable from views? Looks like variable is still not present in the view, nor in controller of redirected path.

Comment: What variable would that be? My answer explains how to make sure sessions work in Laravel 5.2. If there's something that you've tried to fix and are still stuck, you might want to ask a separate question where you can give more details about your particular case.

Comment: I think the questioned issue here is that after redirect, your view should contain test variable stored in Session (because of redirect is chained withVariable method). Problem is Session::all() is still empty even if all the routes are in web middleware group.

Comment: @Fusion I see. Then my previous comment still stands. I think it would be best if you created a new question where you can include your relevant code and details (routes, controller actions, views, session driver used, etc) and then it can be determined better where the problem might be coming from, because if you did all the above then the session should work.